# Need some help for jenkins gradle integration

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am getting some issues with the configuration and setup jenkins to the local gradle project .it's some thing like integration of gradle with jenkins and jenkins will be responsible for building and running the gradle ...initially I tried with cmd execution available at jenkins but its not promising solution .So I feel I need some help for setup gradle plugin for local bild.gradle execution

Comment: You really should add examples and details: error messages, relevant configuration file snippets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Jenkins you use, but with decently recent version you should have a build step type "Invoke Gradle Script" in "Freestyle project" project types, that you should use to execute your gradle build.

Everything is well explained here: https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-jenkins/#create_a_jenkins_job

[image]